# Excel: paste formulas (or data) separately?

Tags: microsoft-excel

(I'm pretty sure the answer is no; but, ...)

The situation is, multiple instances of a spreadsheet, each with a different data set.  If I modify the formulas in one ('master') spreadsheet, is there a way to import/paste those formulas en masse to the other spreadsheets, without losing those other data sets?

Comment: You can always reference the other workbooks with a formula similar to "=Sheet1!A2"

Comment: @EricF I'm familiar with that construct, but I'm not sure how it would help.  I want to apply the new formulas to data sets on other 'free-standing' sheets.

Comment: You can always copy and paste normal can't you?

Comment: I don't think there's an easy way to do this. The only option I can come up with is a VBA routine that loops through all cells and if it finds a formula, copies that to the exact same cell in the other file.

Comment: your question is very broad now. And to solve it there would need either a very clever artificial intelligence, either a very complex definition behind. What do you want to do exactly? Distribute all modified formulas? Are all the spreadsheets has the same structure? How many spreadsheets do you have (you can copy - paste only formulas manually, is it convenient)?

Answer (score 0):

You could change your setup to something like below:

5 input files (data) > 1 output generator (formulas) > 5 output files (data)

where the generator takes an input file, does manipulations and produces an output file. VBA in your generator file would do this in no time at all.